# how to id of button in table using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

```
    <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Subject</th>
                            <th>Message</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          <?php 
                          foreach($fetchContactData as $value)
                          {
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                              <td><?php echo $value['email'] ?></td>
                              <td><?php echo $value['name']?></td>
                              <td><?php echo $value['subject'] ?></td>
                              <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="<?php echo $value['message'] ?>">Show</button></td>
                              <?php   
                            }?>


                          </tbody>
                          <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                              <th>Email</th>
                              <th>Name</th>
                              <th>Subject</th>
                              <th>Message</th>
                            </tr>
                          </tfoot>
                        </table>



      Js code:
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#example1 button").click(function(){

          var id=$(this).attr('value');


          });
        });
      </script>
```

here at each row there is unique id to button. so onclick of that button i want that id in jquery. I tried many searches from stackoverflow but its not working so anyone can help me with jquery part with this exact same code
Here is my js now i want that long message so that i could show it in modal class div.

[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 73ms ---> This is the error i got

Comment: It seems that the IDs of your buttons are always the same: `id="show"`

Comment: you speak about jquery, but where is it on your code ? No javascript here. We surely can't be that clairvoyant.

Comment: bro i did try my all jquery logic but its not working i just need button id on click of that button only

Comment: @prashant welcome to SO, unfortunately the `id="show"` is not unique and it iterates through your PHP loop!

Comment: okay i got ur point and changed the code to what exactly i want. i changes $value['id']to $value['message'] so now this contains a long message and i want to show thart message into bootstrap modal class div

Comment: `$('.btn-warning').on('click', function(e) { console.log( $(this).val() ); });`

Comment: I think you need a loop. with your $("#example1 button") as typically it may return more than one button. so you have to register click event for each button individually. WIthout loop, only the event is triggered for the first button.

Answer (score 0):

An "id" is always used to identify something and therefore should be unique. So you have to make it unique in the first place. Something like this should work.

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Subject</th>
                        <th>Message</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <?php 
                      $i = 0;
                      foreach($fetchContactData as $value)
                      {
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                          <td><?php echo $value['email'] ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $value['name']?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $value['subject'] ?></td>
                          <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="show-<?= $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $value['id'] ?>">Show</button></td>
                          <?php 
                        $i++;  
                        }?>


                      </tbody>
                      <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Email</th>
                          <th>Name</th>
                          <th>Subject</th>
                          <th>Message</th>
                        </tr>
                      </tfoot>
                    </table>
```

In this code, there will be the variable "$i" that is set to 0 in the beginning and just appended to the id "show-". Last step of the foreach-loop, this 0 is just counted up by one.
This will generate and id in the format of "show-0", "show-1" (you could set $i to 1 in the beginning to make it start counting from 1). In jQuery, you then could use the "starts with"-selector to select all buttons and set an onclick event on it. (just one example) https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

```
<script>
$( "button[id^='show-']" ).on('click', clickhandler);
</script>
```

So for every button that has an id starting with "show-" you can make it do the action "clickhandler".

Comment: Yes Bro I got Your point but i changed the code right now. the present code does not work when the $value['message'] is there but the same code worked with $value['id']. Note:MY code without $i that you suggested @clash

Comment: So you want to know what is written in the "id" attribute?
in jQuery $(selector).attr('id'); https://jsfiddle.net/n5376ysr/

Answer (score 0):

your id=button is into loop, so is not unique.
I advise you do not use id, better you can use something like class and in your js script listen click to this, like:

```
<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning button_msg"  value="<?php echo $value['message'] ?>">Show</button></td>
```

Js (jquery)

```
  $(".button_msg').click(function(){
//Do anything
})
```